# Configure the indexPath of each cell of the table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In `UITableView` I set the name of each cell with the following command:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

The variable `list` is nothing more than an array that contains only the description of a particular object coming from a database.

I use another variable called `idt` (which is also an array) containing each `id` of each item of the variable `list`.

Unfortunately I had the need to edit the indexPath, for it contains the same values ​​contained in the array `idt`, because eventually I found problems in my code. Someone could help me on how I can edit the indexPath for variable `idt`?

The variable list contains the following values​​:

> value 01
>
> value 02
>
> value 03

Automatically when you use the command:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

It automatically creates a handle for this cell, and visualize this identifier can use an NSLog command within the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
NSLog(@"%zd",indexPath.row);
```

using this command it returns the following value:

> If I select the Value 01 console log show me 0
>
> If I select the Value 02 console log show me 1
>
> If I select the Value 03 console log show me 2

Now if I put the idt variable, it could look like this:

> If I select the Value 01 console log show me 7
>
> If I select the Value 02 console log show me 12
>
> If I select the Value 03 console log show me 20

For the database the value 01 belongs to the id 7, the value 02 to the id 12, and value 03 to  id 20, would give a lot easier for me.

Comment: What values are stored in `idt` and how are they conflicting with your `indexPath`?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  Perhaps you could post some code that shows how you want to access `idt`.  (You can create new index paths.)

Comment: I edit my post, see now and answer me again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each list Item has a value, and an ID, then you should not have separate arrays, Since they are pair values. You want to use an `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries`

For example:

```
list = @[
         @{@"id" :@"7", @"value":@"value 01"},
         @{@"id" :@"12", @"value":@"value 02"},
         @{@"id" :@"20", @"value":@"value 03"},
         ];
```

Then to display the Text Label on the cell you would do :

```
NSString *ID  = [[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"id"];
NSString *value = [[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"value"];

cell.textLabel.text = value;
```

If you want to test it in the log:

```
 NSLog(@"If I select %@ console log will print %@", value, ID);
```

Output log:

```
If I select value 01 console log will print 7
If I select value 02 console log will print 12
If I select value 03 console log will print 20
```

Comment: I'd be more inclined to do it as an NSArray of NSDictionaries instead. Makes more sense. Rather than implicit pairing between indexes in different arrays within 1 dictionary.

Comment: @Jeff you have a valid point, I edited my answer to use an array of dictionary instead.